# Finding a prime ideal in the ring of dyadic fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have the ring of dyadic fractions $R = \left\{\frac{a}{2^n} : a \in \mathbb Z, n \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}\right\}$. How can I find any prime ideal in this ring? I know by Krull's theorem that some prime ideal exists, but the theorem is proved using Zorn's Lemma / Axiom of Choice, so it is nonconstructive.

I just need any prime ideal (preferably a simple one) so that I can determine where a "proof" I wrote went wrong.

Comment: $R$ is a localization of $\Bbb{Z}$ at the multiplicative subset $\{ 2^n : n \ge 0 \}$. Do you know the characterization of prime ideals of a localization?

Comment: Oh! Duh. Yeah. Any prime ideal in $\mathbb Z$ that's disjoint from $\left\{2^n : n \geq 0\right\}$ can be turned into a prime ideal in $R$ by just mapping $x \mapsto \frac{x}{2^0}$, right?

Comment: Exactly. In particular you can see that prime ideals of $R$ have the form $pR$ where $p$ is any odd prime number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $S= \{ 2^n: n \ge 0\} \subseteq \Bbb{Z}$. Then $R = S^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ is a localization of the ring of integers (actually every intermediate ring between $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ is).

Hence, prime ideals of $R$ have the form $S^{-1}P$, where $P$ is any prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$ disjoint from $S$. These are exactly ideals generated by odd prime numbers.